# How to define both assemblies and non-assembly files that need to be deployed in a ClickOnce application, from within a Visual Studio project?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, clickonce, manifest, publish, mage

So I am trying to figure out if there is a way to define the files and assemblies I need deployed with a ClickOnce app, from within Visual Studio.

I would like to "Publish" the application and not have to make any more modifications with Mage. Especially for continuous integration.

Is this possible? Can I add something to the app.manifest file, to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this by adding a file to the project, and in the properties window, set the "Build Action" to "Content"

You may also have to set the "Copy to Output Directory" property as well.

(this is not tested using ClickOnce, but it works with other build and deploy methods)